# Android error "E/ConfigurationContentLoader: PhenotypeFlag unable to load ContentProvider"

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Recently I Factory Reset my phone and tried running my app on the phone again and now I get this error in `Logcat`:

```
09-18 20:15:57.629 29355-29378/com.******.com E/ConfigurationContentLoader: PhenotypeFlag unable to load ContentProvider, using default values
```

And it just keeps coming, it prints out like 30 of these each second and it happens in every fragment and no matter what I do.

The app worked perfectly before reset but after the reset it keeps spamming this error and I think it might be the cause but I cannot find what it is and what I can do against it.

So my question is, what is this telling me and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: getting same error on motorola z5, lollipop